# How to format json data returned from EF entities in WCF service in standard json format?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, wcf

I have created the following sets of methods in WCF WebServices using VS2015

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISchoolProjectService
    {    
    [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,          
           UriTemplate = "field=news/{id}")]
        IList<Object> NewsService(string id);


    }
```

in its implementation

```
public IList<Object> NewsService(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                _entitites = new SchoolEntities();
                var query = from x in _entitites.NewsAnnouncements select x;                
                switch(id)
                {
                    case "all":
                        return query.ToList<Object>();
                        break;
                    default:
                        return null;
                        break;
                }


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

on service request in browser /field=news/all
I get the following response

```html
{"NewsServiceResult":"Your requested product[{\"Id\":\"02ed1de9-4029-4b94-869d-4be55e82edc8\",\"Title\":\"Relief, happiness and disappointment as VCE results released\",\"Image\":\"47c05ca9-d126-4823-8e16-17d499c78b5d.jpg\",\"Description\":\"For five excruciating days, Natasha Kennedy resisted the temptation to open&nbsp;her VCE results.She was one of more than 2000 students who received their results early due to a&nbsp;technical glitch. At first she thought it was a cruel hoax, and then she was prepared to wait.\",\"PublishDate\":\"2016-04-13T00:00:00\",\"CreatedDate\":\"2016-04-06T10:37:30\",\"UserName\":\"WebAdmin\",\"ShortDescription\":\"For five excruciating days, Natasha Kennedy resisted the temptation to open her VCE results.\"}
```

I wonder is there any chance to format these piece of data as like

```html
{
  
  "field": "news",
  "sortBy": "all",
  "articles": [
    {
      "id": "02ed1de9-4029-4b94-869d-4be55e82edc8",
      "title": "Relief, happiness and disappointment as VCE results released",
      "shortDescription": "For five excruciating days, Natasha Kennedy resisted the temptation to open her VCE results.",
      "urlToDescription": "http://webapischoolproject.yarshatech.com/Detail/NewsAndAnnouncement/02ed1de9-4029-4b94-869d-4be55e82edc8",
      "urlToImage": "http://http://webapischoolproject.yarshatech.com/Detail/NewsAndAnnouncement/47c05ca9-d126-4823-8e16-17d499c78b5d.jpg",
      "publishDate": "2016-12-14T23:37:03Z",
"createDate":"2016-12-14T23:37:03Z"
    },
```

What I really want from json response is to format Description field which has long text into

```
"urlToDescription":"http://webapischoolproject.yarshatech.com/Detail/NewsAndAnnouncement/02ed1de9-4029-4b94-869d-4be55e82edc8"
```

and Image into

```
"urlToImage":"http://webapischoolproject.yarshatech.com/Detail/NewsAndAnnouncement/47c05ca9-d126-4823-8e16-17d499c78b5d.jpg"
```

Comment: If you add <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/> in endpoint behavior of your service you should get json without wrapper. Checkout this blog: http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/11/how-to-expose-json-endpoint-from-wcf.html

Answer (score 0):

its easy:
at first create an object like this and make it your web service output:

```
public class News
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string sortBy { get; set; }
    public Article[] articles { get; set; }
}
public class Article
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string shortDescription { get; set; }
    public string urlToDescription { get; set; }
    public string urlToImage { get; set; }
    public string publishDate { get; set; }
    public string createDate { get; set; }
}
```

then parse your query result in to it.

1-parse the query in to this object:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string NewsServiceResult { get; set; }
}
```

2- parse the `NewsServiceResult` value to array of this object:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
}
```

3-finally you just need to enumerate the array and put it into your output.

Comment: Could you please provide more detailed solution?

Comment: dear @rudolf_franek. i updated my answer. ihope it solves your problem.